# exporting blender model to mixamo with texture?

Tags: mesh, texture-painting, mixamo

hey all so I tried many times to export my own model to mixamo but every time I export it to mixamo than I apply some animation on the rigged body in mixamo , After that I download the animation and import it to blender , but Every time I do this , the character will be full white mesh , no texture on it , I tried to pack and unpack resources but It did not work , I m pretty sure something is wrong or I missed something ? thanks in advance
[image]

the one on the left is the original texture with paint tab , right side is the mixamo one

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1O7YxjnJim0GJDEzWiI1dBICZ48wvq0a6/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Is there anything that stops you just to assign material of your original model? UV is persisted. For deeper investigation we would need to see your file and to know what format you have used for export and import, texture file format, when imported to mixamo you can see the texture?, etc. ... BTW Mixamo accepts FBX or OBJ formats from blender, both exports that I tried from blender are without texture (before mixamo) ... so it is probably blender that doesnt includes material for export.

Comment: thank you for the reply , actually I did not thought about it assigning material it worked though , and I exported FBX with path mode (copy) and on embed textures checked , also a quick question is there a way to assign all materials in one click ? as I m doing for every object copy materials

Comment: there blend file

Comment: Your link needs permission ... please change access to anyone.

Comment: done sorry.......

Comment: You should read and understand this post about exporting materials from Blender: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures

Comment: In general - my bad ... your workflow (described in comment) works for me ... Export from Blender as FBX (path mode Copy) works to import texture into Mixamo and also Export from Mixamo as FBX 7.4 or DAE works to import model with material to Blender. Your file is too new for my old Mac at home, so someone else should check it. (just a notes without confirmation - shader should contains PrincipleBSDF and texture should be in PNG format.)

Comment: Worked also with your file (to make it easier I rigged in mixamo just a body) ... texture is exported in imported to blender ... but there is clearly difference in material node tree, that make sence mixamo cant use whole range of blenders shaders. So I gues it is expected limitation of exporter to FBX or inside mixamo (hard to say) ... but that is not a topic of this site.